# Avoid __new__ to be called every time

Tags: python, metaclass

I understood that classes are instances of metaclasses and that `__new__` is running  before `__init__`, because, you must create an instance before initializing it.

Imagine now the following :

```
import time
class ConfigurationsMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attr):
        # Potentially a long task here (eg: Getting value from a web service)
        time.sleep(2)

        # Which class inherit from me (debug)
        print(f'Class {name}')

        config = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attr)

        #Set a variable to be propagated (Variable coming from web service)
        setattr(config, "URL", "https://stackoverflow.com/")

        return config

class Foo(metaclass=ConfigurationsMeta):
    def __init__(self):
        print(f'{__class__.__name__} : {self.URL}')

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        print(f'{__class__.__name__} : {self.URL}')

class Baz(Bar):
    def __init__(self):
        print(f'{__class__.__name__} : {self.URL}')

e = Foo()
s = Bar()
c = Baz()
```

1. Nice because URL is well propagated as I do have

   ```
   Foo : https://stackoverflow.com/
   Bar : https://stackoverflow.com/
   Baz : https://stackoverflow.com/
   ```
2. I do have now something I don't understand very well :

   `Class Foo` is written after 2 sec

   `Class Bar` is written after another 2 sec

   `Class Baz` is written finally after another 2 sec

So metaclass is executed three times. 
This must explain that as `__new__` is responsible for creating classes, it must be run every time, so three times.

Am I right?

How can I avoid it and make it run only once?

Comment: `__new__` shouldn't get a value from a web service...

Comment: Am I right? - Yes. How can I avoid it and make it run only once? - Have only _one_ class whose metaclass is `ConfigurationsMeta` (or use caches)

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a metaclass here. Assuming you want `URL` to be a *class* attribute, not an instance attribute, you just need to define a base class with a suitable `__init_subclass__` definition. The URL should be retrieved first and passed as an argument to `__init_subclass__` (via a keyword argument in the `class` statement).

```
class Base:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, /, url=None):
        super().__init_subclass__(cls)
        if url is not None:
            cls.URL = url


some_url = call_to_webservice()


class Foo(Base, url=some_url):
    pass


class Bar(Foo):
    pass


class Baz(Bar):
    pass
```

If `URL` should be an instance attribute, then replace `__init_subclass__` with `__init__`:

```
some_url = call_to_webservice()

class Base:
    def __init__(self, /, url):
        self.url = url

class Foo(Base):
    pass

f = Foo(some_url)
```

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines, but even avoiding `__init_subclass__`, simply storing the URL in the superclass (hard-wired), as it seems the OP wants it to be shared and initialised once only

Comment: Probably. I mention `__init_subclass__` mainly to demonstrate how metaclasses usually are overkill for class customization.

Comment: Upvoted. Note: I don't think it changes anything, but the three classes are inheriting in a chain, each from the previous one. They aren't all inheriting from Base directly

Comment: There is one significant difference: it means `url` only has to be passed to `Foo`, since `Bar` and `Baz` will inherit `URL` once `Foo` sets it.

Comment: (Although that requires `url` not be a required argument for when `Foo.__init_subclass__` resolves to `Base.__init_subclass_` and the `url` argument isn't supplied by `Bar` or `Baz`.)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already, you do not need metaclasses.

And you have got an excellent and flexible answer already, which uses `__init_subclass__`.

A flat simple approach is to set the shared attribute in the superclass and let the instances of the subclasses find it (as they normally do up along the chain of instance, class, superclasses)

```
class Configurations:
    URL = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'

class Foo(Configurations):
    def __init__(self):
        print(f'{__class__.__name__} : {self.URL}')

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        print(f'{__class__.__name__} : {self.URL}')

class Baz(Bar):
    def __init__(self):
        print(f'{__class__.__name__} : {self.URL}')


e = Foo()
s = Bar()
c = Baz()
```

Or, if the configuration is more complicated, use a class method to keep the code tidy

```
class Configurations:

    @classmethod
    def create_cfg(cls):
        cls.URL = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
...

Configurations.create_cfg()
e = Foo()
s = Bar()
c = Baz()
```

Both ways initialise the configuration once only and produce

```
Foo : https://stackoverflow.com/
Bar : https://stackoverflow.com/
Baz : https://stackoverflow.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers cover why you don't need a metaclass here.
This answer is to explain briefly what metaclass' `__new__` does: 
it does build your *class* - it is called by the Python runtime itself when it processes a `class <name>(bases, ...): <body>` statement. No, you can't have a class without calling
a metaclass `__new__` method - or at least "the root of all metaclasses", `type`'s `__new__` method.

That said, if for some reason you'd need to have a long task that could be run just once for all classes you create, all you'd have to do would be cache the results of the long task, and used the cached values in subsequent calls.

If for some reason the value can not be cached, and must be performed in the metaclass, you'd have to arrange for your classes bodies themselves to be executed in different treads or using an asyncio loop. More elegant forms might include instantiating a concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor inside the metaclass `__new__` when it is called for the first time (and hold it alive as a metaclass attribute), and after calling `type.__new__` for each class submit the part that takes long as a future.

As you can see, since what you need is just set a class attribute, you should avoid doing this as a metaclass.

Still, the design could be like:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

TIMEOUT = 5

class PostInitParallelMeta(type):
    executor = None
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, ns, **kw):
        super().__init__(name, bases, ns, **kw)
        mcls = cls.__class__
        if not mcls.executor:
             mcls.executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(20)
        mcls.executor.submit(cls._post_init)



class Base(metaclass=PostInitParallelMeta):
    _initalized = False
    def _post_init(cls, url):
        # do long calculation and server access here
        result = ...
        cls.url = result
        cls._initialized = True

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super.__init__(*args, **kw)
        counter = 0
        while not self.__class__._initialized:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            counter += 0.2
            if counter > TIMEOUT:
                 raise RunTimeError(f"failed to initialize {self.__class__}")


class Foo(Base):
    # set any parameters needed to the initilization task
    # as class attributes
    ...
```

PS - I just wrote this and realized the code in the metaclass can safely be put in Base's `__init_subclass__` method - no need for a metaclass at all even for this.